# Javascript returning variable outside of intended markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

Ok, simple thing I'm overlooking here.  The following javascript is returning the `title` variable **outside** the anchor tag rather than inside of it (as the code looks to be written to me).

I know I'm missing something obvious, like a method to return the variable as a string or something similar but I'm not sure what's going on.

Help?

**EDIT: My mistake, it's "view site" which is being returned outside the `<a>` tag**

```
// Convert logo img alt tags into div.caption 's
$(".imgs_wrap img").each(function(i, ele) {
    var title = $(ele).attr('title');
    var description = $(ele).attr('alt');
  $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="caption popup"><p> ' +description + ' <a target="_blank" class="view_site" href="http://'+title+'" />View Site</a></div></p>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistakenly using the self-closing tag syntax when rendering the `<a>`:

**bad line:**

```
$(this).parent().prepend('<div class="caption popup"><p> ' +description + ' <a target="_blank" class="view_site" href="http://'+title+'" />View Site</a></div></p>');
```

**change to:**

```
$(this).parent().prepend('<div class="caption popup"><p> ' +description + ' <a target="_blank" class="view_site" href="http://'+title+'" >View Site</a></div></p>');
```

Comment: I knew it was obvious ;) Thanks!

Comment: np - hive-mind has helped me out with many an embarrassing oversight.